# How to recall component controller in Angular 4 for the same route link?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular4-router

I have got two routing links:

```
/article/1
/article/2
```

These links are related with the same component:

```
{path: 'article/:id', component: HomeComponent}
```

When component is initialized, then after click over link  `/article/2` it does not initialize this component again.

How to fix?

**HTML** is:

```
 <div (click)="setCurrentRole(role)" *ngFor="let item of menuService.getMenuItems(role)"><a
                [routerLink]="[item.url]" (click)="setActiveLink(i, item.url)" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']">{{item.title
                | translate}}</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reload a component :

In your component, on the init hook, subscribe to routing events, and move your init code into a function

```js
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params['id']);
    this.doOnInit();
  });
}

doOnInit() {
  // your old code here
}
```

Subscribing to router events :

```js
constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events.subscribe(events => {
    // Several routing events, take only the last one
    if (events instanceof NavigationEnd || events.constructor.name === NavigationEnd.name) {
      console.log(params['id']);
      this.doOnInit();
    }
  });
}

doOnInit() {
  // your old code here
}
```

Comment: Another way? it is not suitable for me

Comment: I use this:  `<div *ngFor="let item of menuService.getMenuItems(role)"><a
                [routerLink]="[item.url]" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']">{{item.title
                | translate}}</a></div>`

Comment: I did an experiment: `ngOnInit() {

    console.log("ok") } ;` it does not show me `ok` after second click

Comment: Did you subscribe to route events ?

Comment: No, is it necessary? I thought a constructors is called every time

Comment: How to import `ActivatedRoute`?

Comment: If your component isn't destroyed, the constructor won't be called again. All imports are from @angular/router

Answer (score 1):

you are only interest in the id that you change in the url 
then you can do something like that

```
    id: number;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        /// this method will called if you navigate to different id
        this.id = +params['id'];
      }
    )
  }
```